# Add Object Column in Parse

Tags: database, object, parse-platform, properties

I am building up a little Database and want to use Parse as my back-end

I started creating a table with a few objects.

Each object has a "Name" and up to 2 "Ingredients"
These Ingredients are as well Objects in the Table.

for Example:

Name: Animal Trap

Ingredient1: Wood Stick

Ingredient2: Nail

---

Name: Nail

Ingredient1: Metal Shard

Ingredient2: Nail

---

I tried doing it with "String" Columns, but I can't work with strings all the time. I need to be able to get the object from another objects ingredient.

But whenever I try to put some Object into the "Object" Column it says: "Undefined"

[image: Parse Database Preview]

What do I have to put in there?

Comment: Can we see your code?

Comment: I don't have any code yet. I just want to know what I have to put into the column?